# Passing data (list) from view to controller with TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using ASP MVC4 with razor and I'm stuck to return some infos from my view to my controller in a list with the below elements...
I use the TextBox to be able to run my js function...
I use the following (updatesum()) javascript to dynamically calculate in the field the sum of the archer's score in my view:

```
<td> 
    @Html.TextBox("suma["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchScore1,  new{ @onchange = "updatesum()"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchScore1)
</td> 
<td>
    @Html.TextBox("sumb["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchScore2, new { @onchange = "updatesum()" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchScore2)
</td>
<td> 
    @Html.TextBox("sumt["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchTot`enter code here`alScore, new { @onchange = "updatesum()" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x[i].ArchTotalScore)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchTotalScore)
</td> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatesum() {
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            var sua = "suma_" + i + "_";
            var sub = "sumb_" + i + "_";
            var sut = "sumt_" + i + "_";
            suma = document.getElementById(sua).value;
            sumb = document.getElementById(sub).value;
            sum = (suma - 0) + (sumb - 0);
            document.getElementById(sut).value = sum;
        }   
    }        
</script>
```

Do you know if it is feasible to add the result of this javascript function into the TextBoxFor?

Here is the code of my after the modifications suggested:

```
<td> 

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArchScore1, new{ @class = "score" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchScore1)
                </td> 
                <td>>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArchScore2, new{ @class = "score" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchScore2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArchTotalScore, new{ @class = "score" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x[i].ArchTotalScore
                </td> 
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}

<script type='text/javascript'> 
              $('.score').change(function () {
                    var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
                    inputs.eq(2).val(new Number(inputs.eq(0).val()) + new Number(inputs.eq(1).val()));
                });


</script>
```

The 3rd textbox is still not populated.

Comment: Why are your creating your controls with no relationship at all to your model and would never bind to your model when you submit! - `@Html.TextBox("suma["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchScore1`) should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArchScore1)`

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to total? - do you want a total for each row and a grand total?

Comment: Actually, the user put a number in score 1 and score 2 and the sum of the 2 is automatically calculated and filled in Total.

Comment: But you have 4 textboxes per row (in  the 3rd column you have 2 textboxes) Is that correct? And do you want a grand total as well?

Comment: Correct. but the idea

Comment: @DavidE, What is the use of third text box in last td? were you using it for grand total? if yes then why the last textbox is there? what is the use of it?

Comment: Hello actually this  @Html.TextBox("sumt["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchTot`enter code here`alScore, new { @onchange = "updatesum()" }) is used to calculate the sum of score1 and score2. The 2nd one was to try if the manual input is sent through the form (@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x[i].ArchTotalScore) ) --> yes but not automatically populated. So there is an extra textbox used for test that I don't need indeed.... Hope I could clarify what I wan to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to update the rows subtotal. Give the textboxes a class name (say `class="score"`)

```
$('.score').change(function() {
  var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
  inputs.eq(2).val(new Number(inputs.eq(0).val()) + new Number(inputs.eq(1).val()));
});
```

Howver you have multiple other errors in your code. Firstly your manually overriding the names of the inputs so when you post it will not bind to your model. Your need to replace

```
@Html.TextBox("suma["+@i+"]", Model[i].ArchScore1)
```

with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArchScore1, new { @class = "score" })
```

and ditto for the other textboxes

Your textbox for the totals are should not be textboxes (or if they are then they should be disabled) so they do not post back. The calculations MUST be done again on the server when you submit if you need to save them

Comment: Thanks for you help. However, I don't really how I can integrate this jquery script into my code....

Comment: What part don't you understand? Just delete your existing `function updatesum() { ... }` script and replace it with the script in my answer. If its at the bottom of the page (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag then it will work fine. If not, then you will need wrap it inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I have also created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hm6qjdf/) to show you how it works

Comment: Thanks. I actually replace my updatesum() script with your script. I put the script at the bottom of my _layout.cshtml page before the </body> but the script does not run, text is shown instead... (sorry for my stupid questions... :( )

Comment: Look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hm6qjdf/) I prepared for you. I dont understand what you mean by _"text is shown instead"_. Is it inside the `<script type="text/javascript">` tags? And its a script specific to the view so it should be in the view, not the layout

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle. This exactly what I need thanks. However, I still cannot add it to my view :( (I paste the code of my view in answer below)

Comment: Re your edit: Have your inclided `jquery.js`? Check your browser console for for any errors?

Comment: I guess it is yes... Here is what I can see in the source of my page: <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>EncodeResult - Archery Competition Manager</title>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Ok that works now. Thank you !!! I found what was the issue. It's because there were several <td></td> in the <tr> section. I isolated my fields to be calculated in one <tr> and it solved the problem.